# Delete sequential text

Tags: javascript, php, text

I want to remove text with a case like this (visit this `http://jsbin.com/elehug/2/edit` ):
when I checked NEG1 twice, attached "text1 text1", then I check POS1 once, I want "text1" erased, and I also check POS1 once again "text1" erased again, so there is no text in the textarea.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is this tagged "javascript" if you want to do it with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
   var txt = document.getElementById("posbox").value;
    if (txt.length>elem.length){
  document.getElementById("posbox").value = txt.substr(0,txt.length-elem.length);
    }else{
      document.getElementById("posbox").value='';
    }
```

Your corrected php code is:

```
<?php
for ($j = 51; $j <= 53; $j++) {  
echo '
<div id="part'. $j .'" >
<div id="teks'.$j.'">TEXT 2 </div>
<input type="radio" id="pos'. $j .'" name="teks'.$j.'" value="POS" onclick="addPOS(this.previousElementSibling.innerHTML);">POS2</input>
<input type="radio" id="neg'. $j .'" name="teks'.$j.'" value="NEG" checked="checked" onclick="delPOS(document.getElementById(\'teks'.$j.'\').innerHTML);">NEG2</input>
</div>';}
?>
```

Basically I have named the divs properly, changed double quotes around `teks'.$j` to single quotes.

Comment: Hi, @bansi thanks for the response, can you show it on my links? thanks

Comment: @user2413763 I have edited your script. Check if you can see the changes. The [Live Preview](http://jsbin.com/elehug/9)

Comment: Em, @bansi i have some case to do, and edit the codes like this http://jsbin.com/elehug/13/edit (please try on your pad :) ). i try to re-check NEG2 but not erase any text. i expect something wrong in line 27. can you suggest me a problem? thanks

Comment: I have fixed the script. That site cannot run PHP code. I am now at my mobile and cannot test the script. Check if this works. else I can test it morning my time.

Comment: @user2413763 I have posted the corrected PHP code here see my edit. I have not changed code at your pad. The pad you have provided cannot run PHP code, so check this at your web server.

Comment: Thanks bansi, you always be the best